# Labelling the edges of a graph

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, graph-theory, gcd-and-lcm, algebraic-graph-theory

> Let $G$ be a connected graph with $m$ edges. Prove that the edges can be labelled with the positive integers $1,2,…,m$ such that for each vertex with degree at least two, the greatest common divisors amongst the labels on the edges incident to this vertex, is $1$.

One way to achieve that is by ensuring that all vertices have atleast two edges with consecutive labels. But I am not sure if this is always possible.

I found a way to do this whenever the graph has a hamiltonian path or a eulerian circuit. But I could not prove anything in general.

Comment: Why do you think that labeling(sorting de vertices and placing consecutive labels to the edges) is not possible?

Comment: @Phicar I don't know of any algorithm to get such a labelling for a general graph. Can you describe one?